# How can remove this float issue?

Tags: python, string, gis, folium

If there is a different way to do this please let me know. I'm assuming my lat lon columns in my data are causing the float issue. Is there workaround for it?

Here is a sample of the data:

```
year, population, lat, lon, state name
1900, 161772, 44.068203,-114.742043, Idaho
(continued with different populations through 1990)
```

I am also using a geoJSON file for my US states that i got from here:
https://eric.clst.org/tech/usgeojson/

I am trying to make a time slider to show population change in the state of Idaho from 1900-1990.

Full Code:

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import folium
    import re
    import geopandas as gpd
    import matplotlib
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_idaho = pd.read_csv('/content/IdahoPop.csv', dtype=object)
df_idaho.head()

states = gpd.read_file('/content/states.json')
print(states.head())

df_idaho['Year']=pd.to_datetime(df_idaho['Year'])

id_dict={'Idaho': '0'}
df_idaho['state_id']=df_idaho['StateName'].map(id_dict)
bins = 10

df_idaho['color']=pd.cut(df_idaho['Population'],bins,labels=['#C1FFC1','#90EE90','#00EE76','#00CD66','#32CD32','#008000','#2E8B57','#2E8B57','#32814B','#006400'],include_lowest=False)
df_idaho['color'].replace(np.nan,'#32CD32',inplace=True)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-181bcdce2f44> in <module>()
----> 1 df_idaho['color']=pd.cut(df_idaho['Population'],bins,labels=['#C1FFC1','#90EE90','#00EE76','#00CD66','#32CD32','#008000','#2E8B57','#2E8B57','#32814B','#006400'],include_lowest=False)
      2 df_idaho['color'].replace(np.nan,'#32CD32',inplace=True)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/tile.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    239 
    240         rng = (nanops.nanmin(x), nanops.nanmax(x))
--> 241         mn, mx = [mi + 0.0 for mi in rng]
    242 
    243         if np.isinf(mn) or np.isinf(mx):

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

Comment: Show the code used to load the CSV.  The variable `mi` is a string so you can't add `0.0` to it (and *why* add 0.0 to anything?).  You could do `float(mi)`.

Comment: I'm using google colab to host the file for now and this is how I am loading the csv: df_idaho = pd.read_csv('/content/IdahoPop.csv', dtype=object)
df_idaho.head()

Comment: Edit your question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Remove `, dtype=object` from `pd.read_csv`, otherwise all columns are loaded as objects. Additionally, there is a duplicate color value in the `labels` list that you need to change in order for the code to run (`'#2E8B57'`).

Comment: Thank you RJ, that did the job. :)